# if condition for checking a tortoiseSVN update into a linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, svn

I am working with a SVN server into a linux computer.I am trying to develop bash code for making the compilation automatically. The thing is that I do not want to compile the files if there have not been an update into my SVN server. so the first thing I do is checking for updates.

this way:

> if svn update; then
>
> ...
>
> fi

the problem is that even if there are not updates it enters into the if condition as it has to check for updates. I would like to Know if there is a way of checking if an update had occurred or not.

thank you.

Comment: You would need to parse the output from the svn update command.

Comment: I can not do that as the other partners inside the project only know using SVN so I have to try to work with these platform

Comment: Have you tried a svn hook instead? It is basically a bash script executed when the svn server notices "some changes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use svn hooks rather that ad-hoc scripts but you need to place them on the server side.

This said, if you still need to build your own script you need to notice that the `svn update` command will evaluate to true if no error has happened. This has nothing to do with the command really updating files or not. Consequently, you need to check your current svn version and the svn version of the remote repository. If they are different, then you can perform the svn update and any other command needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

REMOTE_REPO="svn://path/to/remote/repo"
LOCAL_REPO="/path/to/local/repo"

REMOTE_REV=$(svn info $REMOTE_REPO | grep '^Revision:' | awk {' print $2 '})
LOCAL_REV=$(svn info $LOCAL_REPO | grep '^Revision:' | awk {' print $2 '})

if [ $REMOTE_REV -ne $LOCAL_REV ]; then
    cd $LOCAL_REPO
    svn up

    # Add any other command here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
[ $(svn up|wc -l) != 2 ] && (
  echo "Your code here"
) || (
  echo "No changes."
)
```